# vs code - python function with many input arguments

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code as my primary coding editor. I found its behavior for python function with many arguments is unexpected. For example, if I call the function in the following way

```
my_function(
    param1, param2, param3, param4,
    param5, param6)
```

after typing the right bracket, the leading spaces will be automatically removed by the editor (see below), which is really unwanted.

```
my_function(
    param1, param2, param3, param4,
param5, param6)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: do you have the python extension installed?

Comment: Yes, I installed the python extension. Everything works fine (autocomplete, function argument hint, etc) except for the closing bracket.

Comment: This is solved. I upgraded my vs code to the newest version.